# Python/Requests: Correct login returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a python application logs in to a remote host via basic HTTP authentication. 
Authentication is as follows:

```
def make_authenticated_request(host, username, password):
    url = host
    r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r

test = Looter.make_authenticated_request("http://" + host + "/status/status_deviceinfo.htm", user, password)
```

This error is printed:

`401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url`

Strange thing is that this doesn't always happen. It randomly fails/succeeds, for the same host with the same credentials.

Login is however correct, and works flawlessly in my browser. I'm no python ninja. Any clues ?

Comment: Pehaps it's the way you are gain auth.  I almost always avoid using the built in auth parameter and either auth by passing in the correct parameters or headers depending on the endpoint.  OR better yet, use a session instead.  s = requests.Session()
res = s.get(url, auth)
if res.status_code == 200:
s.get(url)

Comment: I've used the snipper provided by @reticentroot which uses sessions. Still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might rewrite it to look something like this.. change it around however you need or like.  The point here is that i'm using a session and passing it around to make another requests.  You can reuse that session object to make other requests.  Now if you making lots of requests an authing in each time like your code suggests.  The site could be locking you out, which is why a session works better because you don't have to continue to auth in.

```
import requests

class Looter(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.s = None

  def create_session(self, url, username, password):
    # create a Session
    s = requests.Session()
    # auth in
    res = s.get(url, auth=(username, password))
    if res.status_code == 200:
      self.s = s

  def make_request(self, url):
    self.s.get(url)
    #do something with the requests

l = Looter()
l.create_session(url, username, password)
# print the session to see if it authed in
print l.s.status_code
```

Comment: I've user your code. I upvoted it for its elegance. However, the request sent in create_session returns 200, after that make_request returns false. The remote endpoint has no locking mechanism.

Comment: Hmm instead of using the method make_requests use the session directly.  So instead of print l.s.status_code do l.s.get()

Comment: If that still doesn't work then it's not the session it might be the url endpoint itself. You can debug further by printing  the full response. Eg. Print l.s.content or print l.s.json() or print l.s.text sometimes the failed response will tell you why it failed in more detail

Comment: Argh, the amount of mistakes in my previous comment.. My issue was solved using your code but adding ` s.auth = (username, password) ` in the `create_session` method, instead of passing is to `s.get()`. Go figure why. Thanks though, marking as accepted !

Comment: Awesome and no problem:-)