# Python requests.Session() randomly returns 401 even after authenticating

Tags: python, authentication, session, python-requests, http-status-code-401

I've been using requests.Session() to make web requests with authentication. Maybe 70% of the time I'll get a status_code of 200, but I also sporadically get 401.

Since I'm using a session - I'm absolutely positive that the credentials are correct - given that the same exact request when repeated may return 200.

Some further details:

- I'm working with the SharePoint REST API
- I'm using NTLM Authentication

To circumvent the problem, I've tried writing a loop that will sleep for a few seconds and retry the request. The odd thing here is that I haven't seen this actually recover - instead if the first request fails, then all subsequent requests will fail too. But if I just try again - the request may succeed on the first try.

Please note that I've already reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195170/python-requests-correct-login-returns-401-unauthorized), but the suggestion is to use requests.Session(), which I'm already doing and still receiving 401s.

Here's some code to demonstrate what I've tried so far.

```py
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from urllib.parse import quote

# Establish requests session
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)

# Update the request header to request JSON formatted output
s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 
                   'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

def RetryLoop(req, max_tries = 5):
    ''' Takes in a request object and will retry the request
        upon failure up the the specified number of maximum 
        retries.

        Used because error codes occasionally surface even though the 
        REST API call is formatted correctly. Exception returns status code 
        and text. Success returns request object. 

        Default max_tries = 5
    '''

    # Call fails sometimes - allow 5 retries
    counter = 0

    # Initialize loop
    while True:
        # Hit the URL
        r = req

        # Return request object on success
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r

        # If limit reached then raise exception
        counter += 1
        if counter == max_tries:
            print(f"Failed to connect. \nError code = {r.status_code}\nError text: {r.text}")

        # Message for failed retry
        print(f'Failed request. Error code: {r.status_code}. Trying again...')

        # Spacing out the requests in case of a connection problem
        time.sleep(5)

r = RetryLoop(s.get("https://my_url.com"))
```

I've additionally tried creating a new session within the retry loop - but that hasn't seemed to help either. And I thought 5 seconds of sleep should be sufficient if it's a temporary block from the site, because I've retried myself in much less time and gotten the expected 200. I would expect to see a failure or two, and then a success.

Is there an underlying problem that I'm missing? And is there a more proper what that I can re-attempt the request given a 401?

** EDIT: @Swadeep pointed out the issue - by passing in the request to the function it's only calling the request once. Updated code that works properly:

```
def RetryLoop(req, max_tries = 5):
    ''' Takes in a request object and will retry the request
        upon failure up the the specified number of maximum 
        retries.

        Used because error codes occasionally surface even though the 
        REST API call is formatted correctly. Exception returns status code 
        and text. Success returns request object. 

        Default max_tries = 5
    '''

    # Call fails sometimes - allow 5 retries
    counter = 0

    # Initialize loop
    while True:

        # Return request object on success
        if req.status_code == 200:
            return req

        # If limit reached then raise exception
        counter += 1
        if counter == max_tries:
            print(f"Failed to connect. \nError code = {req.status_code}\nError text: {req.text}")

        # Message for failed retry
        print(f'Failed request. Error code: {req.status_code}. Trying again...')

        # Spacing out the requests in case of a connection problem
        time.sleep(1)

        req = s.get(req.url)
```

Comment: The problem is, in the RetryLoop function, you are not doing anything, except checking the status code and sleeping. Where is the part where you make the get call again after sleeping? Unless I am not missing anything.

Comment: Ok - I see your point. I thought the `r = req` would re-execute the get call - but it's probably executing prior to being passed into the RetryLoop? Is that order correct?

Comment: Correct. r = req will simply assign the response passed to the function to a variable r. In your function, r and req are basically same.

Comment: That fixed it right up - I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I propose.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from urllib.parse import quote

# Establish requests session
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)

# Update the request header to request JSON formatted output
s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

def RetryLoop(s, max_tries = 5):
    '''Takes in a request object and will retry the request
        upon failure up the the specified number of maximum 
        retries.

        Used because error codes occasionally surface even though the 
        REST API call is formatted correctly. Exception returns status code 
        and text. Success returns request object. 

        Default max_tries = 5
    '''

    # Call fails sometimes - allow 5 retries
    counter = 0

    # Initialize loop
    while True:
        # Hit the URL
        r = s.get("https://my_url.com")

        # Return request object on success
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r

        # If limit reached then raise exception
        counter += 1
        if counter == max_tries:
            print(f"Failed to connect. \nError code = {r.status_code}\nError text: {r.text}")

        # Message for failed retry
        print(f'Failed request. Error code: {r.status_code}. Trying again...')

        # Spacing out the requests in case of a connection problem
        time.sleep(5)

r = RetryLoop(s)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.